# Validation (CSS 3.0): 'text-shadow' is not a known CSS property name

Tags: visual-studio-2010, css

I have installed both the [CSS Intellisense](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7211bcac-091b-4a32-be2d-e797be0db210) and [web standards](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a15c3ce9-f58f-42b7-8668-53f6cdc2cd83) updates then restarted VS2010. I've also verified that I have "CSS 3.0" selected in the "CSS Version Validation" drop down that's part of the Style Sheet toolbar. I still don't see any intellisense and I continue to get this error for all CSS3 properties.

Sure the styles work in (newer) browsers, but this is annoying.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

open windows explorer and navigate to this directory:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Packages\1033\schemas\CSS
```

make a backup copy of this file:

```
css30.xml
```

then open the above file (any text editor will do) an search for "text-shadow"

I'm assuming the entry is not there.  If not add this line:

```
<cssmd:property-def _locID="text-shadow" _locAttrData="description,syntax" type="composite" description="Enables shadow effects to be applied to the text of the element." syntax="Example: h1 {text-shadow: 20px 12px 2px #333;}" enum="inherit initial none" />
```

EDIT: in my file this entry is just below the entry for "text-emphasis-position"

Comment: I don't have a 1033 dir. It stops at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Packages where I only see a debugger folder. I may not have sp1 installed for VS2010. I'm trying that now.

Comment: that may not be your install directory.  check your shorcut that opens VS2010.  where is that pointing?

Comment: also i'm assuming you have admin rights on your machine.  if you don't have admin rights you may not be able to make this change

Comment: I found it, it was in ProgramFiles(x86). You're correct, that line is not in the css30.xml file... any idea why? I'm guessing I'll run into this same problem with other properties.

Comment: Most likely it was a simple oversight - who knows. IDE's are so complex and try to cover so much it amazes me more stuff isn't missed

Comment: I'm sure there should be a more appropiate way to get IntelliSens to update itself.

Comment: 4 year old question on a 7 year old VS...so no.